# How to Auto Filter except a specify a string using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In the Excel file I've hundreds of value including .(dot) values. Would like to Autofilter all the values except .(dot) value in VBA Macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not know anything about your data, you could do something like this to filter on the first column for all rows that do not start with a dot:-

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D20").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>.*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Could you please help me to locate the dynamic range? My test data varies in excel sheet and its not static

Comment: Update this to change `A5` to be your top-left-most cell in your range:  `ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>.*", Operator:=xlAnd`